# Computing marginals on a graphical model in Python

Tags: python, inference, graphical-model, marginal-distribution

I am looking for libraries available from Python to compute marginals on an undirected graphical model (i.e. a random field) with loops.

Some algorithms for this could be LBP (loopy belief propagation) or GBP (generalized belief propagation), although I don't need to use a specific algorithm.

I checked [SciKit learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) but they don't seem to have much for graphical models.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [PyMC](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc) (documentation is available as [pdf](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v35/i04) and [html](http://pymc-devs.github.com/pymc/index.html))

See also [this section](http://pymc-devs.github.com/pymc/modelbuilding.html#the-potential-class) on using arbitrary factors.

Comment: Thanks! On a quick look I didn't see anything to compute marginals. Perhaps I missed it?

Comment: for the example in the [tutorial](http://pymc-devs.github.com/pymc/tutorial.html), the plotting of the marginal posterior distribution for one of the parameters is shown in [section 3.5.3](http://pymc-devs.github.com/pymc/tutorial.html#sampling-output)